# Pentaho Job stays at start and does not continue

Tags: pentaho, jobs, kettle, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

So, I start running my Job with just one transformation, it starts and stays that way. It doesn´t throw any errors. 
The transformation alone runs perfect and fast, but the Job doesn´t.
What can the problem be? I´ve been searching without success.
[Print of my Job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zKrh.png)

Comment: See the Picture please!!!

Comment: The problem is in the transfo, not the job. Does it uses parameters? Does your transfo open the same sql table for input and output?

Comment: Have you given any condition in scheduling? any time interval? if so then remove it,it will work proper.

Comment: thanks!!! yes my client gave a schedule condition.. its done now!